# How to force texmaker to break lines in the editor

Tags: texmaker

So Texmaker is configured in such a way that math equations only break if there are spaces between operations and symbols. I use a very narrow editor view in order to look more easily at the equations in the text view. This results in Texmaker cutting off important parts of equations that I'm attempting to edit and increases my risk of committing a mistkate. An example would be

[image: Texmaker cuts off parts of equations in editor view]

Is there a way to disable this behaviour and force Texmaker to just display continous characters? Honestly I don't see why you would even make this your default behaviour, for me it's very easy to identify the different parts of equations in the source file, as long as I can actually see them.

Comment: unrelated but never have a blank line before a displayed equation

Comment: It was just to display the problem. I don't actually leave them just like that